# Where is the WebOS Palm Host application found?

Tags: webos

I just watched a video about unit testing WebOS applications and they used the "Palm Host" application. Where can this app and documentation on how to use it be found?

Comment: This is the video I was refering to http://www.weboshelp.net/getting-started-with-webos/745-webcast-unit-testing-in-palm-webos-christian-sepulveda-of-pivotal-labs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

palm-host was a small web server that allowed testing Palm webOS applications in a desktop browser, usually Safari, instead of in the device emulator.  With the improvements made in the emulator since the early SDK releases, Palm has removed support for this because the internal Webkit version used on the device has drifted a bit from the version Apple has in their Safari build, and they've got external debugger support on the device/emulator now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Palm-Host is supported anymore. It used to allow you to run Palm apps in Safari and use that debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it wasn't Palm Mojo or maybe they just meant they were using a Palm host?

http://developer.palm.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

[Palm Developer](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1758) or [Palm Developer Main Page](http://developer.palm.com/).

I found it pretty helpful.

Comment: What do those links have to do with "Palm Host"?